# Full HTML not loading with Nightmare JS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, nightmare

I am trying to scrape a website using Nightmare JS and when I try loading the link in my browser , the full HTML gets rendered but with NightmareJS , i am able to load only the  tags and it does not execute the scripts.

Link: http://justmoviesonline.com/play.php?id=0Bx80UYxFGc5E0VqpWQ_hgz1ujPp/

With Nightnmare JS

my Code is :

const nightmare = NightMare()

```
nightmare.goto(url)
  .evaluate(function () {
    return document.body.innerHTML
  })
  .end()
  .then(function (body) {
    $ = cheerio.load(body)
    $('script').each(function(){
      console.log($(this))
    }
    )
```

Basically I want to extract the  src and that is probably loaded after the scripts are executed.

Any help/pointers would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to scrape from the page? What is the script your are trying to run? If you provide more info I'll be able to solve your issue.

Comment: Hi well I have solved the issue, I am trying to get the video source inside the <video> tag. But this part of the HTML was getting generated by the script inside the <p> tag, when CH in turn depends on the external JavaScript library. I think the problem with Nightmare is it will not load any external JavaScript(my guess). So the solution I did is get the HTML body and extract the SRC of the third party library , then force reload the DoM with jsDom by passing the library in jsDOM config. That seems yo do the trick.

Comment: okay glad you got it working. Also nightmare has a method .inject(type, file), so you should be able to load your script with that, which will be easier.

Comment: Okay thanks, can I provide a URL as filepath? Or it should be a local file?

Comment: I believe it needs to be a local file.